# Scrolling with overlow-x doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: css, scroll, flexbox

I need horizontal scrolling for the list of tags on mobile screen. The following code works perfectly on Chrome, but doesn't work on Firefox.

I tried setting a fixed width to .taxonomy-wrap, but it didn't work.

```css
.taxonomy-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    overflow-x: auto;


    a {
        flex:  0 0 7rem;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scrolling has worked, the problem is that Firefox touch screen emulation doesn't seem to emulate dragging: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_Mode#Toggling_touch_event_simulation